# UITextField resignFirstResponder working a bit then not

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I add in a UiTableViewCell a `UITextField *gasPrice;` like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier;
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row < [self.userCarsArray count])
        CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d%@", indexPath.section, indexPath.row, [[self.userCarsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] idCar]];
    else if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == [self.userCarsArray count])
        CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d%@", indexPath.section, indexPath.row, @"AddCar"];
    else
        CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d%d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 2) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        else {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
            UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170, 10, 125, 30)];
            textField.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
            textField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.20f green:0.30f blue:0.49f alpha:1.0f];
            textField.placeholder = @"0.00";
            textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
            textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; // no auto correction support
            textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone; // no auto capitalization support
            textField.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
            textField.tag = 0;
            textField.delegate = self;
            textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeNever; // no clear 'x' button to the right
            [textField setEnabled: YES];

            [cell addSubview:textField];

            [textField release];

            gasField = textField;
        }
    }

    // Selection style.
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    // Vehicles cells.
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        // ...
    }

    // General cells.
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Measurement System";
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

            if ([EcoAppAppDelegate measurement] == MeasurementTypeMile)
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Miles";
            else
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Meters";
        }

        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

            if ([EcoAppAppDelegate measurement] == MeasurementTypeMile)
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Gas Price (gal)";
            else
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Gas Price (L)";

            // Gas price.
            if ([EcoAppAppDelegate gasPrice] != 0.00)
                gasField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", [EcoAppAppDelegate gasPrice]];
        }
    }

    // Information cells.
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        // ...
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Then, to manage the keyboard when the user is done (because I use a keyboard without return key), I have those functions:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(done:)] autorelease];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:doneButton animated:YES];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];

    // Save gas price.
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""])
        [EcoAppAppDelegate setGasPrice:0.00];
    else
        [EcoAppAppDelegate setGasPrice:[textField.text floatValue]];

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    // Hide keyboard.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

And the function for the navigation bar button "Done":

```
- (void)done:(id)sender {
if ([gasField canResignFirstResponder]) {
    [gasField resignFirstResponder];
}

[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
```

}

So it works fine first, when I stay in my settings view controller, but when I do other stuff on some other cells (that push other view controllers, come back, etc), it stops working. It is probably because the gasField pointer has disappeared or something like that, the gasField object tho is still different from nil.

Any idea why it does that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using gasField as a `property`. use

```
self.gasField
```

Comment: I am not using it as a property, just declare the object in the interface in the .h file.

Comment: I just did and it is worse, I explain: I have a UITableViewController called SettingsViewController and in section 1, 2 cells. The first one is the measurement system's choice, when you click on the cell it pushes a view controller with 2 choices, miles or meters. When I select one, it comes back to the settings controller and update the section 1. So as a property, it adds another textfield, and I have one textfield for miles, and one textfield for meters... Weird.

Comment: You do not need to add textFields like this. You could just use something like `textField.hidden = YES` or `textField.hidden = NO`

Comment: I am not adding any textfield, I just add one at the cell's creation (see code above updated). By putting the textfield as a property, it does something weird.